# Django REST Framework -- How to resolve ForeignKey to Actual Value, not index?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a **model** such as:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    build = models.ForeignKey(Build, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and a **view**:

```
class JobViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
```

and a **serializer**:

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
```

The only issue is when I access the API endpoint, I receive data, but the `build` property from `Job` model is the actually integer of the foreign key. I want the actual value from that key (which is also a model in my Django rest framework.

I have search a lot and I found some promising articles, but was not getting correct results when I tried various things. I am still new to Django...Can any of you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a serializer for `Build` like:

```
class BuildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Build
```

Next in `JobSerializer` do like:

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    build = BuildSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('name','build')
```

Comment: is `fields = ('name','build')` required? And if so, what effect does it have?

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo you are adding a custom field (`build`) to the serializer, so you need to mention that in the `fields`,  or else this will lead to `AssertionError`. If you want a subset of the default fields to be used in a model serializer, you can do so using `fields`. learn more here -> http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include

Comment: Thank you, this works! I do not believe `fields` is needed though. I could not find that info in the documentation and I have tried it without explicitly specifying `fields` and it works.

Comment: Also, is this method preferred or is it better to set `depth = 1` (as in the answer below)? Thanks!

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo I'm sorry, You are correct. `fields` attribute is not mandatory. But if you use the `field` attribute, then you have to explicitly set all the fields(mandatory for custom fields) that you want to serialize. With respect to `depth=1`, this depends on your requirement. In future if you want to customize the way the serialization(`BuildSerializer`) is done you'll need to define the field yourself or else you can use `depth=1`

Answer (score 2):

Use a `depth` attribute.

```
class BuildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Build
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Is this method the "best practice" or it is better to specify serializers for each `ForeignKey`? Both work...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `depth` attribute when you want to get all the attributes of a member field in your `JobSerializer`.

**Example**, all the fields of the Build Model.If you want to fetch just specific fields,

Like, all fields of a user model except the password field must specify a serializer for the foreign key of the user.